# My field group changes are not showing in view mode

Tags: nodes, entities

I've got some fields in a field group that aren't listening to me. I first created the content type and added about 10 fields, about 8 in one vertical tab, 2 in another. I saved the content type, came back the next day, started making some changes to the display, but none of the new fields I've added show up. I placed fields in the existing groups, created new groups, and at one point did a clone of the form. Is there a known bug, or have I just screwed something up? Either way how can I get my functionality back?

Comment: Did you add some content that could show up in those new fields? Maybe I misunderstand the question. Could you share some screenshots?

Comment: Have you checked your display settings for that content type?

Comment: It looks like it's a theme issue. Empty fields won't display. How can I properly theme nodes using the field group module? Would I simply modify the node--content-type.tpl.php template file, or also have to have a field template?